# SignalR err 404

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I copied a lil sample from SignalR documentation that uses SignalR hub. Under development environment (VS) it works fine, after I upload it to my host I got error 404 for signalr/hub.
I checked with SignalR FAQ and they recommend the following -

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/signalr/hubs") %>'></script>
```

and,

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Unfortunatelly, none of them worked for me...

Any suggestions ?

Comment: What is the name of the project? Make sure to not name your project SignalR

Comment: Can you include a trace of the HTTP request that is 404'ing please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer I was looking for. I had a feeling that it had something to do with my routing on the production server.
http://blog.tjitjing.com/index.php/2010/09/asp-net-routing-gives-404-error.html

```
 <system.webServer> 
      <modules> 
        <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" /> 
        <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" /> 
      </modules> 
    </system.webServer>
```